# Schedule SQL Agent Job on RDS SQL Instance to restore latest backup weekly from S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, powershell

Scenario: I want to schedule an SQL Agent job weekly on RDS SQL instance to restore database which should access the latest backup file from S3. I'm using sp msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database to restore the backup.

exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='MyDatabase', @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/ServerName/DatabaseName/FULL/DatabaseName_FULL_20201122_030001.bak';

Question: How can I achieve to find the latest full backup file name from S3 to use in above restore script? It would be great if someone can guide with steps/scripts if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Vikas

Comment: I think you likely want to look into creating an SSIS Package if you want your SQL Server to purely handle this, otherwise it might be easier to have a secondary process in AWS that always moves the latest backup to a special S3 bucket that your SQL instance can reference.

Comment: Thanks @J.D.   - I will explore the first option using SSIS package. I'm interested in 2nd option suggested by you. If possible, could you share some basic steps how to create a process in AWS to copy the latest file to specific location.

Comment: Unfortunately that's more of a ServerFault or StackOverflow question, as I am not versed enough in AWS on how to do it, though I know it's possible. If I get a chance to do some research I'll see if I can provide more info to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Plase try to collect from msdb database the latest backup with a query like that:

```
SELECT  
   A.[Server],  
   A.last_db_backup_date,  
   B.backup_start_date,  
   B.expiration_date, 
   B.backup_size,  
   B.logical_device_name,  
   B.physical_device_name,   
   B.backupset_name, 
   B.description 
FROM 
   ( 
   SELECT   
       CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
       MAX(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date) AS last_db_backup_date 
   FROM    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
   WHERE   msdb..backupset.type = 'D' 
   GROUP BY 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name  
   ) AS A 
    
   LEFT JOIN  

   ( 
   SELECT   
   CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,  
   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,   
   msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
   msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id  
WHERE  msdb..backupset.type = 'D' 
   ) AS B 
   ON A.[server] = B.[server] AND A.[database_name] = B.[database_name] AND A.[last_db_backup_date] = B.[backup_finish_date] 
ORDER BY  
   A.database_name
```

and the combine the result with your code to build a proper parameter for the rds_restore_database stored procedure.

---

Comment: Hi @MBuschi, thanks for your answer. However, the script shared by you is really great but will not resolve my problem.

Comment: The reason - my test server is in different AWS account (Test Account) but the backups are taken on Production server which is in Production AWS account. The script shared by you supposed to be run on Production serve but can't access that server which connected to Test VPN. But I can access S3 bucket from Test account (i.e. test server) where restore script will run.  Therefore, I was looking for a script which can give me latest full back file name from S3 'FULL\' backup folder and I can use this file name in my restore script.

Comment: So your question is how to get the latest file from a s3 bucket.
You should use aws CLI with something like that:


    $ KEY=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'` $ aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$KEY ./latest-object